# How to Save jBPM 5 Process Definition Created via API?

Tags: jbpm

Once I have created a Process Definition as described in the [documentation section 5.1.3](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.1/userguide/ch05.html#d0e779) how do I then save that Process as BPML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.  What I found is that I can do this as the last line in the mentioned example from the User Guide and I will get the XML for the Process.

```
System.out.println(XmlBPMNProcessDumper.INSTANCE.dump(process, XmlBPMNProcessDumper.NO_META_DATA));
```

If there is a better way please let me know.